# <sqlite3.h> not found

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite

When I input `#include <sqlite3.h>` to visual studio c++ it says cannot open source file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which #include? Have you set the include path?

Comment: oh sorry #include <sqlite3.h>

Comment: Have you told visual studio where this is on your hard drive? You need to add additional include paths